# Scala and implicit imports?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, implicit

First of all I have to tell I am not that experienced with Scala and lately I read some piece of code that I don't understand how it works.

This sample code was using `Future` and normally they all need `scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global` but that was not declared anywhere in the project code. When I try to use `Future` in my IntelliJ project, it is complaining that I have to declare a `ExecutionContext` somewhere ...

Same for the the `import scala.collection.JavaConverters._`. The sample code was using `asScala` all the time without importing the converters...

Is there a way to configure such things project wide in Scala (or may be a trick in IntelliJ)...

Answer (score 4):

In Intellij, you can use the shortcut `Ctrl+Shift+Alt++` (Implicit hints) to find out what implicits are used (and what implicits are missing) in your code (they appear in light gray and you can `CTRL+click` on them). See: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/edit-scala-code.html#scala_hints

So if you go ahead and open the code you do not understand in IntelliJ with **implicit hints** activated, you will be able to see where the implicits are defined.

For your case: try to use `import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global` in the files you need an implicit `ExecutionContext`.

> Is there a way to configure such things project wide in Scala (or may be a trick in IntelliJ)...

No, you have to define the implicits somewhere in scope or import them. (Companion objects are also applicable). Read this for a more detailed explanation: https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/implicit-parameters.html

Answer (score 4):

I don't think this is IntelliJ related.

One possible explanation would be that the code you refer to declared these implicits in some globally imported scope, like a `package object`. In that case, any member of the package would see the implicits declared in this object.

Comment: Yes, what I was trying to explain is how he can find out how the code he does not understand works. Opening that in IntelliJ with implicit hints activated will reveal where the implicits are defined.

Comment: @FlorianBaierl Sure, this is a good trick. I was trying to give the most likely explanation for the "automatic implicit import" that he was describing.